# making a responsive navigation bar

Tags: javascript, dom, responsive-design, navbar

I have just started learning javascript and i've come across this problem.The problem is i'm making a resposive layout and i want to show the navbar moving from right to left when i click menu button but i cant seem to do that.I have watched different tutorials and tried bunch of things but none of them seem to work. I was hoping someone could help me in this.

**here's my css for the navbar**

```
.navbar{
                    display: block;
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    right: -100%;
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 90vw;
                    max-width: 400px;
                    padding: 70px 0;
                    background-color: lightskyblue;
                    transition: all ease 200ms;

                    .toggle{
                    box-shadow: -2px 2px 20px black;
                    left: 0%;
                    }
```

**and here's the script i have written**

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar')
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu--active')
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.menu--close')


menuBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    nav.classList.add("toggle")
})
```

Sorry for asking such a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

well everything is good you are not removing the toggle class on clicking the close button so:

```
 closeBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    nav.classList.remove("toggle")
})
```